# Background image will not appear in IE 8

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Im applying a background image to the body element and am only getting the background color.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background:#FF6CC5 url('assets/pink_out.png') no-repeat top center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.4;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { /* Due to variations between browsers, it's best practices to zero padding and margin on lists. For consistency, you can either specify the amounts you want here, or on the list items (LI, DT, DD) they contain. Remember that what you do here will cascade to the .nav list unless you write a more specific selector. */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;   /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can escape from their containing div. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from any elements that follow. */
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px; /* adding the padding to the sides of the elements within the divs, instead of the divs themselves, gets rid of any box model math. A nested div with side padding can also be used as an alternate method. */
}
a img { /* this selector removes the default blue border displayed in some browsers around an image when it is surrounded by a link */
    border: none;
}

/* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of selectors that create the hover effect. ~~ */
a:link {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: underline; /* unless you style your links to look extremely unique, it's best to provide underlines for quick visual identification */
}
a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator the same hover experience as the person using a mouse. */
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ~~ this container surrounds all other divs giving them their percentage-based width ~~ */
.container {
    padding-top: 175px;/***************COPY************/
    width: 1100px;
    max-width: 1260px;/* a max-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too wide on a large monitor. This keeps line length more readable. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
    min-width: 780px;/* a min-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too narrow. This keeps line length more readable in the side columns. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout. It is not needed if you set the .container's width to 100%. */
}

/* ~~ the header is not given a width. It will extend the full width of your layout. It contains an image placeholder that should be replaced with your own linked logo ~~ */
.header {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: none;
}

/* ~~ These are the columns for the layout. ~~ 

1) Padding is only placed on the top and/or bottom of the divs. The elements within these divs have padding on their sides. This saves you from any "box model math". Keep in mind, if you add any side padding or border to the div itself, it will be added to the width you define to create the *total* width. You may also choose to remove the padding on the element in the div and place a second div within it with no width and the padding necessary for your design.

2) No margin has been given to the columns since they are all floated. If you must add margin, avoid placing it on the side you're floating toward (for example: a right margin on a div set to float right). Many times, padding can be used instead. For divs where this rule must be broken, you should add a "display:inline" declaration to the div's rule to tame a bug where some versions of Internet Explorer double the margin.

3) Since classes can be used multiple times in a document (and an element can also have multiple classes applied), the columns have been assigned class names instead of IDs. For example, two sidebar divs could be stacked if necessary. These can very easily be changed to IDs if that's your preference, as long as you'll only be using them once per document.

4) If you prefer your nav on the right instead of the left, simply float these columns the opposite direction (all right instead of all left) and they'll render in reverse order. There's no need to move the divs around in the HTML source.

*/
.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}

/* ~~ This grouped selector gives the lists in the .content area space ~~ */
.content ul, .content ol { 
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px; /* this padding mirrors the right padding in the headings and paragraph rule above. Padding was placed on the bottom for space between other elements on the lists and on the left to create the indention. These may be adjusted as you wish. */
}

/* ~~ The navigation list styles (can be removed if you choose to use a premade flyout menu like Spry) ~~ */
ul.nav {
    list-style: none; /* this removes the list marker */
    border-top: 1px solid #666; /* this creates the top border for the links - all others are placed using a bottom border on the LI */

}
ul.nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666; /* this creates the button separation */
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited { /* grouping these selectors makes sure that your links retain their button look even after being visited */
    display: block; /* this gives the link block properties causing it to fill the whole LI containing it. This causes the entire area to react to a mouse click. */
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus { /* this changes the background and text color for both mouse and keyboard navigators */
    background: #FFF;
    color: #FF6CC5;
}

/* ~~ The footer ~~ */
.footer {
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;/* this gives IE6 hasLayout to properly clear */
    clear: both; /* this clear property forces the .container to understand where the columns end and contain them */
    background-color: none;
}

/* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following the last floated div (within the #container) if the #footer is removed or taken out of the #container */
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
.footer .footer a strong {
    text-align: center;
}
.footer .footer a strong {
    text-align: center;
}
.footer .footer {
    text-align: center;
}
.container .content p {
    color: #80181F;
}
.container .content p {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
-->
</style><!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>
.content { margin-right: -1px; } /* this 1px negative margin can be placed on any of the columns in this layout with the same corrective effect. */
ul.nav a { zoom: 1; }  /* the zoom property gives IE the hasLayout trigger it needs to correct extra whiltespace between the links */
</style>
<![endif]-->


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="officers.html">Officers</a></li>
      <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li></ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">

 <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;Friday, October 19th, the Leadership class. T-Shirts, Hoodies, Eye Blacks, and Luminaries were sold to help support this awareness. </p>
</div>




 <!-- end .content --></div>

<div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;width:1000px;clear:both;">
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
<!--
/*
Cross browser Marquee script- © Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
For full source code, 100's more DHTML scripts, and Terms Of Use, visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com
Credit MUST stay intact
*/

//Specify the marquee's width (in pixels)
var marqueewidth="1000px"
//Specify the marquee's height
var marqueeheight="333px"
//Specify the marquee's marquee speed (larger is faster 1-10)
var marqueespeed=3
//configure background color:
var marqueebgcolor="transparent"
//Pause marquee onMousever (0=no. 1=yes)?
var pauseit=0

//Specify the marquee's content (don't delete <nobr> tag)
//Keep all content on ONE line, and backslash any single quotations (ie: that\'s great):

var marqueecontent='<nobr><img src="assets/pink out 007.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 008.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 010.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 014.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 016.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 021.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 022.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 023.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 025.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 026.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 027.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 029.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 031.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 033.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 034.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 036.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 043.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 060.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 061.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 062.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 081.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 101.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 113.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 162.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 169.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"><img src="assets/pink out 179.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="pinkout"></nobr>'


////NO NEED TO EDIT BELOW THIS LINE////////////
marqueespeed=(document.all)? marqueespeed : Math.max(1, marqueespeed-1) //slow speed down by 1 for NS
var copyspeed=marqueespeed
var pausespeed=(pauseit==0)? copyspeed: 0
var iedom=document.all||document.getElementById
if (iedom)
document.write('<span id="temp" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;top:-100px;left:-9000px">'+marqueecontent+'</span>')
var actualwidth=''
var cross_marquee, ns_marquee

function populate(){
if (iedom){
cross_marquee=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("iemarquee") : document.all.iemarquee
cross_marquee.style.left=parseInt(marqueewidth)+8+"px"
cross_marquee.innerHTML=marqueecontent
actualwidth=document.all? temp.offsetWidth : document.getElementById("temp").offsetWidth
}
else if (document.layers){
ns_marquee=document.ns_marquee.document.ns_marquee2
ns_marquee.left=parseInt(marqueewidth)+8
ns_marquee.document.write(marqueecontent)
ns_marquee.document.close()
actualwidth=ns_marquee.document.width
}
lefttime=setInterval("scrollmarquee()",20)
}
window.onload=populate

function scrollmarquee(){
if (iedom){
if (parseInt(cross_marquee.style.left)>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
cross_marquee.style.left=parseInt(cross_marquee.style.left)-copyspeed+"px"
else
cross_marquee.style.left=parseInt(marqueewidth)+8+"px"

}
else if (document.layers){
if (ns_marquee.left>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
ns_marquee.left-=copyspeed
else
ns_marquee.left=parseInt(marqueewidth)+8
}
}

if (iedom||document.layers){
with (document){
document.write('<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><td>')
if (iedom){
write('<div style="position:relative;width:'+marqueewidth+';height:'+marqueeheight+';overflow:hidden">')
write('<div style="position:absolute;width:'+marqueewidth+';height:'+marqueeheight+';background-color:'+marqueebgcolor+'" onMouseover="copyspeed=pausespeed" onMouseout="copyspeed=marqueespeed">')
write('<div id="iemarquee" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px"></div>')
write('</div></div>')
}
else if (document.layers){
write('<ilayer width='+marqueewidth+' height='+marqueeheight+' name="ns_marquee" bgColor='+marqueebgcolor+'>')
write('<layer name="ns_marquee2" left=0 top=0 onMouseover="copyspeed=pausespeed" onMouseout="copyspeed=marqueespeed"></layer>')
write('</ilayer>')
}
document.write('</td></table>')
}
}
-->
</script>
</div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="footer">
      <!-- #BeginDate format:Am1 -->January 15, 2013<!-- #EndDate -->
    </strong></p>
    <!-- end .footer --></div>

  <!-- end .container -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried background-color and background-image. Still only background-color displays.
Chrome and Firefox display the background-image just fine.
I've tried with jpg and png images.
The image is linked correctly.

**WHAT CAN I BE MISSING?**

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle for this that shows exactly what problem you're having. It could be any number of things, but if you create a test case that we can all easily see you will more than likely get better answers

Comment: No need to hide your CSS using HTML comment tags <!-- --> since about 1997.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V9RHU/

Answer (score 0):

something is wrong with your image. If you use another image it works fine in IE8.
See example: http://jsfiddle.net/V9RHU/1/

```
background-image: url("http://placehold.it/300x400");
```

Comment: I think it may be because it is png, so this is an invalid test